# SetState and React-Native lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm taking my first steps with React-Native. I can not understand why with the following code I get the value `"data" = []` inside _refreshData (console.log(this.state.data);)

I have this code from *Learning React Native* book:

```
class SimpleList extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 console.log("Inside constructor");
 this.state = { data: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
 console.log("Inside componentDidMount");
 this._refreshData();
}
```

...

```
_refreshData = () => {
 console.log("Inside_refreshData");
 console.log(NYT.fetchBooks());         
 NYT.fetchBooks().then(books => {
  this.setState({ data: this._addKeysToBooks(books) });
 });
 console.log("This is data: ");
 console.log(this.state.data);
};



function fetchBooks(list_name = "hardcover-fiction") {
 console.log("Inside fetchBooks");
 let url = `${API_STEM}/${LIST_NAME}?response-format=json&api- 
 key=${API_KEY}`;
 return fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
   return responseJson.results.books;
 })
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
}
```

Debugging (with console.log) I see that "data" = [] even if I just called the `setState` and from the log I see that the fetch returned my values ...
This is the call log:

[image: Debug]

Can you explain why please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `fetchBooks` and `setState` are asynchronous and finish *after* you log state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first it's promise and asynchronous, and it's not guaranteed that when you log your data also you receive the data, so when you are in `componentDidMount` and call `console.log(this.state.data);` maybe the data is not returned yet. think it took 2000 milliseconds to return the data from api. so you call

```
NYT.fetchBooks().then(books => {
   this.setState({ data: this._addKeysToBooks(books) });
});
```

and then this code as I said took 2000 milliseconds, but as I said you immediately log the data so, because at this time data is not filled you see the empty array.but if you want to see the data you can log it here :

```
NYT.fetchBooks().then(books => {
 console.log(books);
   this.setState({ data: this._addKeysToBooks(books) });
 });
```